# Can't align image view properly in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show the image aligned to the top in the relative layout and the shadow should be around the image and not around the layout. What is going wrong I can't understand.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="162dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how the image looks when preview in design mode. notice the white background that is coming because of drop shadow and it looks like eventhough the actual image is smaller but the imageview is taking relative layout parameters to drop shadow. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Wild guess: your container is too small for the image.

Comment: Try android:adjustViewBounds="true" and/or android:scaleType="fitStart" to see if they make any difference.

Comment: @bstar55 android:adjustViewBounds="true" did get me expected results. I tried that before but I guess I was playing with lot of things :) Thanks again... Thanks Der Golem as well for taking time to reply.

Comment: @lazyguy Glad to hear it!  I moved this into an Answer below for acceptance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need add the adjustViewBounds property.  That property defaults to false...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="117dp"
    android:layout_height="162dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" <-- ADD THIS
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

- Here selector file:

  ```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <stroke       
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
  </shape>
  ```

Hope this might help.